# Bulk edit custom excerpt text in WordPress

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-field, bulk

Is there a way to bulk edit the custom excerpt text without going to each post and open it? When we have 300 posts it can be a very time consuming process.

Comment: There is nearly always a way, but what exactly do you want to do? What are the specific conditions?

Comment: "extract"? Do you mean custom excerpt?

Comment: I mean excerpt sorry!

Comment: Still not a very clearly stated question. In answers below you seem to indicate that you want to be able to add some text - the same text - to each of ca. 300 excerpts, but it's still not clear under what conditions you want the change to occur - or whether you're seeking some entirely different functionality!  If all you want to do is add something that appears with every excerpt, you'd just use a filter function - a pretty simple operation in most cases.

Answer (score 2):

[Search RegEx](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/search-regex/) is a good plugin to be able to search and replace (optionally with grep) through all posts, pages, excerpts, comments, titles and meta.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'm quite having difficulties to create custom regex, I will have to learn...I have a custom text for each post. The text should go to the excerpt and is not the same. It's a summary of the post. So, in order to manually introduce the text, I will have to find the right post. I don't know how I can achieve that with Search RegEx even if it's a powerful tool.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking to edit each post's except in bulk or via quick edit?

If so, I wrote a plugin to do that, see http://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-bulkquick-edit/.

Be warned, this is only for posts and pages. If you want to edit excerpts for custom post types, then you'll need to purchase the premium version.